# Cannot find module when importing pure Typescript package

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to import a Typescript class from one of my Node packages and I am getting the following error:

```
    module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@sap/api'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
```

In this file:

```
import { Plugin } from "@sap/api";

new Plugin();
```

Which imports from this index.ts file:

```
export { Plugin } from "./src/plugin";
```

Which refers to "src/plugin.ts":

```
export class Plugin {
    constructor() {}

    onLoad() {}

    onUnload() {}

    onReload() {}
}
```

When I shift click on the import in VSCode it takes me to the correct file.

What am I doing wrong? I am new to Typescript, so sorry if it is a nooby mistake.

Comment: Is `@sap/api` an NPM package?

Comment: No it is a link to a git branch.

Comment: Using `npm link` or something like that? Does `node_modules/@sap/api` exists, or does this live somewhere else?

Comment: There is a folder in the project with the following hierarchy: "node_modules/@sap/api" which contains all the files.

Comment: alright that *should* work for regular includes, but I did just find this github discussion: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12398

Comment: That discussion suggests that you shouldn't directly use .ts file but instead have a .js and .d.ts files. Basically, build your dependencies separately. I don't know if that has changed since 2016.

Comment: Can you show your tsconfig.json?